# Auto-edit row in a Silverlight DataGrid

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid

Is it possible for the DataGrid to automatically enter edit mode when the user starts typing on the keyboard, without having to hit F2 or double-click with the mouse first?

I've tried those 2 solutions:

**Define only a CellEditingTemplate (no CellTemplate) :** doesn't work. the datagrid always displays a textbox but the user still has to double-click or press F2 to enter edit mode

**Handle KeyDown event and call BeginEdit:**

```
private void DataGrid_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as DataGrid).BeginEdit();
}
```

This works, but I lose the first key the user has pressed. I could work around this problem but I'm looking/hoping for a better solution.

Thank you!